# Выборка данных многие-ко-многим

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Есть таблица книг:

```
BookID | BookName
```

Есть таблица авторов этих книг:

```
AutorID | FirstName | LastName
```

И есть связующая таблица bookautor:

```
BookID | AutorID
```

Необходимо сделать выборку таким образом чтобы по нажатию на автора результатом был вывод названий всех книг определенного автора.
Вот метод из моей модели:

```
public function showBook($id){

        $query0 = $this->db->query("
            SELECT DISTINCT book.BookName 
            FROM book 
            JOIN bookautor ON book.BookID = '".$id."'
        ");

        return $query0->result();
}
```

Здесь аргумент `$id` который принимает функция `showBook` это номер id записи в базе данных которому соответствует автор. Но такой запрос выдает только название одной книги. Подскажите, как вывести название всех книг одного автора.

Comment: Почему в SQL-запросе вы берете $id в апострофы? Неужели BookID хранится в таблице как строка?

Comment: > Почему в SQL-запросе вы берете $id в апострофы?

Почему нет? ISBN, например.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

примерно так (три запроса — по одному на каждого из авторов):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae7e8d/5)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table book (b int, n text);
create table bookauthor (a int, b int);

insert into book values
   (1, "утро")
  ,(2, "день")
  ,(3, "вечер")
  ;

insert into bookauthor values
   (1, 1)
  ,(1, 2)
  ,(1, 3)
  ,(2, 2)
  ,(2, 3)
  ,(3, 1)
  ,(3, 3)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select distinct book.n
from book
join bookauthor
on bookauthor.b = book.b
where bookauthor.a = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae7e8d/5/0)**:

```
|     n |
|-------|
|  утро |
|  день |
| вечер |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select distinct book.n
from book
join bookauthor
on bookauthor.b = book.b
where bookauthor.a = 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae7e8d/5/1)**:

```
|     n |
|-------|
|  день |
| вечер |
```

**Query 3**:

```
select distinct book.n
from book
join bookauthor
on bookauthor.b = book.b
where bookauthor.a = 3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae7e8d/5/2)**:

```
|     n |
|-------|
|  утро |
| вечер |
```

Comment: а что значит ba1 в строке "join bookauthor ba1"?

Comment: не понятно что значит b.b, b.n, ba1, что это и как это?

Comment: *а что значит ba1 в строке "join bookauthor ba1"?* — псевдоним (alias) для таблицы `bookauthor`. она два раза участвуте в запросе — тут без псевдонимов просто не обойтись. а для таблицы `book` псевдоним `b` я объвил просто для краткости.

Comment: `b.b` — эквивалентно `book.b`, `b.n` — `book.n`

Comment: А зачем вам здесь два джойна авторов? Второй джойн ничего полезного не делает. Вы, видимо, хотели изначально по книге найти автора, а потом по автору найти все его книги, отсюда и ошибка. Но в этом случае (по книге найти автора) достаточно было приджойнить книгу второй раз по автору и выбросить из запроса таблицу авторов

Comment: @BOPOH, да, вы правы в обоих случаях — и второй join не нужен, и ошибка называется «недосокращал». спасибо!

Comment: @Nevada, я исправил ответ в соотвествии со справедливым замечанием (см. комментарии выше), и, на всякий случай, заодно убрал смутившие вас псеводнимы.

Answer (score 2):

Видимо, так:

```
    $query0 = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT book.BookName FROM book 
JOIN bookautor ON book.BookID = bookautor.BookID where AutorID = '".$id."'");
```

Comment: SQL-код тоже нуждается в форматировании.